# MYSQL ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE with more than one key?

Tags: mysql, key, duplicates, insert-update

Say i have a record with id=1, b=20 and c=30. id is my primary key.
I would like to insert into the database a new record only if there is no record with b=20 and c=30.
So far i have set a primary key to id but what about b & c? How can i do that query?
Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create a unique key on B and C with.

```
ALTER TABLE MyTable ADD UNIQUE MyIndex(b,c);
```

Comment: Ok got it to work thanks, i end up with INSERT INTO table (name, b, c) VALUES ('test', '20', '30') ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE name = 'update' which works but what if i don't want to update anything? Should i go for "ignore" ??